# How can I install a present-day version of glibc on CentOS 5, without disturbing any existing software?

Tags: centos, glibc

I would like to run present-day versions of git, python, curl, and other common programs on a machine that is permanently stuck on CentOS 5. I have been able to walk the compiler version up far enough to feel like I have a shot at this, but my progress was stopped cold when the versions I was trying to update to went beyond the glibc that existed when CentOS 5 went EOL. How can I get my new software to find a recent version of glibc without doing anything that disturbs the things that are presently running?

Ideally, this would be achievable without having to restart the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Tutorial on how to add glibc without overwriting the system one from the project.
Its used to test builds.
A more complicated part would be to direct the installed compiler to use the compiled lib version instead of the system one.

https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds